# php - writing url holding array query variables

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to post an array of variables taken using form data as in checkboxes like this:

`<input type="checkbox name="parameter[]" value="XML"/>`

`<input type="checkbox name="parameter[]" value="test"/>`

`<input type="checkbox name="parameter[]" value="action"/>`

When this data is submitted, I can see in the Google chrome console, the variables are each posted as `parameter[]`.  I can enumerate over the posted values using a

`foreach ($_REQUEST['parameter'] as $param)` construct.

Due to the way my program is set up, how do I go about writing a query string in which I can send the data through GET request.  For example writing:

`taskpage.php?parameter[]=xml&parameter[]=test&parameter[]=action`

doesn't seem to post the parameter data as an array.

Any advice on how to write this string?

Comment: `$_GET['parameter']` should contain an array. If not than your fault is somewhere else. What does `var_dump($_GET['parameter'])` output?

Comment: Hmm, it's `NULL`.  For some reason it's not getting posted...Sorry!  Bloody typo!!! Goes bangs head off of desk....

Comment: But just to confirm, it is possible to pass an array through GET or POST by typing `page.php?parameter[]=XML&parameter[]=test`

Comment: Remove [] ! Use 
page.php?parameter=XML&parameter=test 
 and $_GET['parameter']

Answer (score 0):

Notice parameter[] != parameter .

It works if you remove the [].

```
taskpage.php?parameter=xml&parameter=test&parameter=action
```

Then take a look to $_GET['parameter']

```
var_dump($_GET['parameter'])
```